# Android error FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I would like to ask why this network connection will appear FileNotFoundException error, I find a lot of places have not found the answer
Thank you first

```
public static void sendOldHttpRequest(final String address, final IHttpCallbackListenet httpCallbackListenet) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                Log.i("tzf", "run: "+address);
                URL url = new URL(address);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }

                httpCallbackListenet.onFinish(response.toString());

                reader.close();
                inputStream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                httpCallbackListenet.onError(e);
            } finally {

                if (urlConnection!=null){
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

error log:

```
03-05 20:59:49.835 17180-17268/com.example.tangzhifeng.paperairplane W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://moment.douban.com/api/stream/date/2017-03-05
03-05 20:59:49.835 17180-17268/com.example.tangzhifeng.paperairplane W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
03-05 20:59:49.835 17180-17268/com.example.tangzhifeng.paperairplane W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
03-05 20:59:49.836 17180-17268/com.example.tangzhifeng.paperairplane W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
03-05 20:59:49.836 17180-17268/com.example.tangzhifeng.paperairplane W/System.err:     at com.example.tangzhifeng.paperairplane.util.HttpUtil$2.run(HttpUtil.java:61)
03-05 20:59:49.836 17180-17268/com.example.tangzhifeng.paperairplane W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Most likely, Android is getting an HTTP 404 response from `https://moment.douban.com/api/stream/date/2017-03-05`. I do not know why.

Comment: Maybe the file is protected. Or bots trying to retrieve the file receive a different result than the user. Try to retrieve an HTML file. open a stream to google.com (or any other site) and try to get the index file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An *HttpURLConnection* will throw a *FileNotFoundException* for HTTP status codes 400 and above. You can use getResponseCode() to check the response status code before reading the content. Maybe your request is bad? Or you don't have the access to requested resource.

You could do sth like this

```
InputStream inputStream;
int responseStatusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
if( status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ) { 
    inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
    //Get more information about the problem
} else {
    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
}
```

Comment: Have you included proper permissions in your manifest file? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Permission to add, because before HTTP403

Comment: Now it is possible, it is possible to do a limited access to it, thank you